# Apache not responding, installing CKAN 2.7.2 in Centos 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos7, ckan

I have installed CKAN 2.7.2 in Centos 7 (64x)

I have followed this links with several modifications: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7

Tomcat 7 works ok, SOLR works ok, Redis is installed and returns PONG on port 6379. Database test created without errors.

I have created:

- `/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi`
- `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ckan_default.conf`

BUT, I always get:

- the welcome page "Testing 1,2,3" at http://www.mydomain
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.76 using http://www.mydomain:8080

It seems that requests to web server are not redirected to WSGI script which should redirect to the CKAN instance.

I get no errors in the log, and I don't know where to look to find why this happens.

Comment: Anything appearing here? /var/log/httpd/ckan_default.custom.log or any other logs in this dir?

Comment: Thanks, everything works great!. I restarted tomcat (like in ubuntu package install) instead of http, now it should be service httpd restart. Just one thing: Database name (ckan_default) and postgresql user (ckan_default) can be changed????

Comment: I'm not clear on whether the wiki was deficient or you just didn't follow it exactly, but if the wiki can be improved, please go ahead! The other question, please start a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

When you add or change the Apache config, you need to reload/restart Apache:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

(I think you must have followed the instructions in the wrong order)